# many elements of a listbox to another

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, listbox

This is the first time I use this medium to ask for help. I wanted to know how , in my code , include two listbox . One that makes querying the database and , through a button , send it to the other, and to do so with more than one option , and then , as in the php code to put the data from the second listbox on a table database. Thank you.

```html
<?php
include("server.php");
$conexion = mysql_connect($server,$user, $pass) or die ("<br> No se puede conectar con la base de datos");
$conectarbase = mysql_select_db ($bd);

$consulta = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM modalidad")

?>
<html lang = "es">
  <head>
    <meta charset = "iso-8859-1"/>
    <meta name = "description" content = "Ejemplo de HTML5"/>
    <meta name = "keywords" content = "HTML5, CSS3, Javascript"/>
    <title>PRECEPTORÍA</title>
    <link rel="shortcut icon" href="./style/favicon.png" /> 
    <link rel = "stylesheet" href = "./style/style.css">
  </head>
  <body class = "body">
    <section class = "section">
      <div class = "div">
        <form>
          <fieldset id = "fieldsetalum">
            <legend id = "legendalum">Registro de nuevos alumnos</legend>
            <select name="combo1" multiple size="8">
              <?php
while ($fila = mysql_fetch_row($consulta))
{
echo "<option value='".$fila['0']."'>".$fila['1']."</option>";
}
?>
            </select>
            <select name="combo2" multiple size=></select>
          </fieldset>
        </form>
      </div>
    </section>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Stop using *mysql** functions. They are deprecated. Next thing, what you want exactly.

Comment: I think you will need to use sessions to build the second combo box values into an array while you assemble the main one - I will see if I can make a framework for that which you can build on. Where would the values be for the second level - `$fila[2]];` etc?

Comment: @ShakaDiocares Try putting the new code block on a php page and see what it does - you should be able to put your database values into it I hope. Let me know if that is anything like what you want.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your form needs an action to submit to itself:

```
     <form name="form" id="form" action="<?php echo echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER["REQUEST_URI"]); ?>" method="post">
```

You could add an onChange(); event to your `select1` dropdown

```
     <select name="combo1" multiple size="8" onChange="submit_this();">
```

and have a JavaScript script in your `<head>`

```
     <script language="javascript"> function submit_this(){ this.form.submit();}</script>
```

Then you would have to use php to collect the values from the submitted page

```
      $combo1 =  mysqli_real_escape_string( $_POST['combo1'] );
```

and then you could return the page with the second dropdown, constructed in much the same way as you made the first one, using the data you get back from the first one to set up the second one. You could wrap the first dropdown in an `isset()`:

```
        if( !isset( $combo1 ) ){
        // make your first select boxes 
        }
```

and the second one in

```
        if( isset( $combo1 ) ){
        // make your second select boxes if combo1 returned a value
        }
```

so that they will only appear when needed.

As @NanaPartykar says, mysqli is the only way to go.

It will be dependent on JavaScript, so, if you prefer, you could have a submit button instead of the JavaScript function:

```
     <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Pick Sizes" />
```

This looks a handy referenc e for how to use select boxes: [PHP code to get selected text of a combo box](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18268068/php-code-to-get-selected-text-of-a-combo-box)

I hope this will give you an idea of how it could be done - the SESSION variables remain to be properly defined in the loop for the second dropdown but they will probably come directly from your database at that point rather than from the session array used for demo purposes.

All values are set as numbers;

`intval();` converts whatever is submitted to an integer to clean it up.

Then you can get back the corresponding value of what was submitted from the session variable you set from your database originally.

That way you will only be getting a single number value from your dropdowns which you can use to look up to get the answer you want

```
  <?php session_start(); ?> 
  <!DOCTYPE html>
  <html lang = "es">
  <head>
  <title>PRECEPTORÍA</title>
  </head>
    <body>
    <form action="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['PHP_SELF']) ?>" method="post">
    <?php
    $main_opt = array();
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'] = array();
    $main_opt[0] = "Select Item";      
    $main_opt[1] = "Ice Cream";
    $main_opt[2] = "Trousers";
    $main_opt[3] = "Tee Shirts";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][1][0] = "Select Flavour";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][1][1] = "Vanilla";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][1][2] = "Chocolate";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][1][3] = "Strawberry";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][1][4] = "Tuttifrutti";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][2][0] = "Select Colour";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][2][1] = "Black";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][2][2] = "Red";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][2][3] = "Green";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][2][4] = "Blue";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][3][0] = "Select Size";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][3][1] = "Small";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][3][2] = "Medium";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][3][3] = "Large";
    $_SESSION['opt_vals'][3][4] = "X Large";
    $i = 0;
    if(!isset($_POST['combo1']) && !isset($_POST['combo2'])){
        echo '<select name="combo1" onChange="submit();">' . "\n";
        //while ($fila = mysqli_fetch_row($consulta)){
        while($i < count($main_opt)){
        echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$main_opt[$i]."</option>\n";       
             $o = 0;
             // load your sub options array here
             if(!$_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i]) $_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i] = array();
             while($i < count($_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i])){
             $_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i] = $o;
             if(!$_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i]) $_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i] = array();
             $_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i][$o] = $_SESSION['opt_vals'][$i][$o];
             $o++;
             }
         $i++;
         }
     echo '</select>'  . "\n";    
     }else{
         if(intval($_POST['combo1']) >= 1) $_SESSION['combo1_val'] = $combo1_val =intval($_POST['combo1']);
         if(intval($_POST['combo1']) >=1){
             $i = 0;
             echo '<select name="combo2" onChange="submit();">' . "\n";
             while($i < count($_SESSION['opt_vals'][$combo1_val])){
             echo "<option value='".$i."'>".$_SESSION['opt_vals'][$combo1_val][$i]."</option>\n";
             $i++;
             }
         }
     echo '</select>'  . "\n";
     }
     if(intval($_POST['combo2']) >= 1) $_SESSION['combo2_val'] = $combo2_val =intval($_POST['combo2']);
     if($_SESSION['combo1_val'] >=1 && $_SESSION['combo2_val'] >=1){
     // use the result to do  whatever you want
     echo 'Thank you! You have selected ' . $_SESSION['opt_vals'][$_SESSION['combo1_val']][$_SESSION['combo2_val']] . " " . $main_opt[$_SESSION['combo1_val']] . '.';
     }    
     // Do any mysqli adjustments to your database here
     // reset to go again
     if($_SESSION['combo2_val'] >= 1){
     $_SESSION['combo1_val'] = 0; 
     $_SESSION['combo2_val'] = 0;
     }
     ?>
             </form>
             <a href="<?php echo htmlspecialchars($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']); ?>">Click to start a new selection</a>
          </body>
     </html>
```

You could remove `onChange="submit();"` and replace it with a normal submit button on the form if you prefer.

Comment: Thank you very much for the answer, but I can not fully understand. I do not speak English and the translator destroys everything they tell me , if you could be kind enough to correct my code would understand better, but thank you very much alike.