# How to get the right info to my <select> with php

Tags: php, model-view-controller, echo

So I'm using php and trying to echo some stuff to `<select>` options from database.

First I want to echo let's say all Cars to the first `<select>` (I can do this) but then I want to echo the SELECTED Car's models to the next `<select>` and I can't do that. I'm pretty novice with all of this stuff. Also I'm using MVC.

From view:

```
<select name="card_id"> 
<?php foreach ($cars as $car) { 
    if (isset($car->id)) { 
       echo "<option value=\"" . $tcar->id . "\">"; 
       echo $car->car . "</option>\n"; 
    } 
} ?> 
</select> 
<p>Choose model</p> 
<select name="model_id"> 
<?php foreach ($models as $model) { 
    if (isset($model->id)) { 
       echo "<option value=\"" . $model->id . "\">"; 
       echo $model->model . "</option>\n"; 
    } 
} ?> 
</select>
```

From the model view:

```
public function getAllCars()
{
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM cars";
    $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    return $query->fetchAll();
}
```

I don't know how the model to pick the car model should look like, but I guess it would be something like this:

```
 public function getmodels()
    {
        $sql = "SELECT * FROM models WHERE
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->execute();
     return $query->fetchAll();
    }
```

Also I don't fully understand the part that's inside the select tag so if you could explain it thoroughly to me it would be nice.

Comment: can you show some code then only anyone can help you

Comment: Bring some code here...

Comment: If you want to echo car model next to car ID, may that mean $cars and $tutkinnonosat are actually two arrays of same size with different values?

Comment: Sorry I had the wrong names in the code. Now they're right.

Comment: This might be of some use: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/34361452/many-elements-of-a-listbox-to-another/34367418#34367418 The arrays are only there to show what is where - you would load your real thing with your sql query. You still are submitting the page though.

Answer (score 0):

It sounds like you want to dynamically update (i.e. without a page refresh) the second select box with the models for the selected car type. You can't do this with just PHP. You'd need to do use javascript to send an additional request to the server with the selected car id and then return a list of models to populate the select box.

If you *were* to make selecting a car actually submit the form that the select is inside (I wouldn't recommend this for UX reasons), you could then grab the selected ID in your PHP script and then populate the second select box accordingly.

Comment: What should I do with javascript?  I'm so sorry I'm such a novice with these things.

Comment: I'm afraid that's too broad a question. It'd involve making an AJAX call to the server with the necessary data and then the server responding with the data you require in some format you can then parse and loop over to generate the HTML for the select box. I'd recommend using jQuery.

Answer (score 0):

You are mostly there, but I have a couple of thoughts.

1) You need to modify your database slightly.  Your models table needs a carId field that your chosen car id  ( $id ) can map to

```
#cars example
id   name
1    Ford
2    Chevy

#models example
id  carId  name
1   1      Mustang
2   1      Taurus
3   2      Camaro
4   2      Corvettte
```

2) As a few people pointed out, if you have trying to keep the car selector and model selector on the same page, it would require some solid JavaScript work. Let's stick to PHP for now.  This requires a person to select a car, hit submit, and move on to the next page to choose a model

3) On the next page,  you can access all of the relevant models with a query like

```
"select * from models where carId = $id"
```